# How to add group talk in my CV?

Tags: resume, skills, student

I recently gave a presentation on the research that I have been conducting with my group. It was a group talk. We all talked for 3-4 minutes, for a total of 10 minutes. This talk was the end of the Summer REU presentation. How can I add this to my CV in the presentation and talk section? Thanks!

Comment: Is that really worth to add in the CV?

Comment: You probably shouldn't. A 10 minute talk really doesn't sound like something that should be on a CV.

Comment: How long is your CV? If it's a one-page CV, I wouldn't bother, but if you're including more detail for each position held you could put it in the section on duties/responsibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in adding a single presentation/talk to your CV.

However, if you really want to do it, one way to go about it is to add a responsibilities section for each workplace and below the current one state something like this: academic research presentation. However, reading this on your CV hiring manager will more likely assume that you gave more than one presentation.

I.e.: *Workplace: University/Institute X | Position: Researcher | Responsibilities: my other responsibilities, n-th responsibility) Academic research presentation*

Comment: Presentations are often added to academic CVs. However, these are presentations at conferences and such and not internal presentations. Unless someone asks for this (and unfortunately some institutions do), I wouldn't add a presentation to my CV unless I don't have any scientific publications.

Comment: I have a couple of presentations ( mostly an hour talk) in my CV that I gave on my own. This was the end of the project talk that I thought might look good on my CV since it was in front of many people. From everyone's suggestions, it seems like it is not worth adding it to the CV.